# How to take the only latest version of items as package

Tags: packages, package-designer

I want to make a package containing only the latest version of a selection/tree of Sitecore items.

Is there any way I can make achieve this with the Package Designer?

Comment: Not at a computer, but I created a module in the market place called "Coast". It provides copy/paste abilities for items/trees. One of the features only copies the latest version. It is also two-click. 1) Click the copy tree button 2) copy to clipboard

Answer (score 12):

Yes you can but not with 1 click.

It will require some manual work but if your tree is not too big then it would be fine.

1. Open the Package Designer.
2. Add the items you want (Add Items statically)
3. Type the Source Name
4. Select the SOURCE and click on PREVIEW
5. Select the item versions you want to remove, right click and EXCLUDE

[image]

I hope that helps :)

All the best

Comment: Thanks Leo. 
I was also able to with following steps.
1.Publish the item and sub items in todays date.
2.Create a dynamic package, by specifying publish date filter as today's 
    date. 
3.we could see latest item(with only one latest version) that was published 
   was included in the item package.

Comment: I am glad you found this way. That was interesting!